# IF condition comparing with true / false

Tags: php

Hey guys i am using simple function to check if user try to search for something already.  My code looks like this:

```
public function getNumberOfQuery(){
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "user", $this->getUsername(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            if ($row['query'] < $row['max_query'])
            return TRUE;
        }

    }catch(PDOExeption $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $con->errorInfo();
    }         
 }
```

Nothing special right? I try to echo `$row['query']` and `$row['max_query']` and it display right data from database. Problem is that i am using something like:

```
if ($data->getNumberOfQuery() == TRUE); {

// CODE 
}
```

Problem is that dispite the fact i manualy put  query bigger then max_query in database the code up here is still execute. And it shouldnt right?
Can somebody look at it and tell me what i am doing wrong? I never use to work with TRUE / FALSE so maybe i just didnt understand it right.

Comment: Please be aware that this will create a *new* connection to the database *every time* you call this method.

Comment: Comparing a count with TRUE is conceptually wrong and if I saw that line I would start looking for a bug. `if ($data->getNumberOfQuery() > 0) {`  is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have spotted the syntax error already, but here's the explanation:

```
if (...); {
    //  ^ - wrong
   ...
}
```

An `if` statement executes **the following statement** if the condition is `true`. Observe:

```
if (true)
    echo 'foo';
echo 'bar';
```

No brackets are used, only the next line "belong to" the `if` statement.
If you want to tie a whole *block* of code to the `if` statement, group it with brackets:

```
if (true) {
    echo 'foo';
    echo 'bar';
}
```

Now, what you're doing is this:

```
if (...)
    ;

{
    ...
}
```

You're immediately terminating the **statement following the `if`** with a `;`, so the `if` executes an empty statement. The then following code block `{..}` is always executed, because it's not tied to the `if` at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($data->getNumberOfQuery() == TRUE); {
```

Try to remove **;** after )

Comment: Good eyes! An explanation of why that's important would be good.